# Changing bundle identifier causes app to fail in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I received an app recently and need to take ownership of it, therefore I need to change the organization section of the bundle identifier, but not the product name. Every search I've done seems to be centered around changing the product name but not the organization name.

When I change the orgaization name in the plist, the app no longer runs in the simulator and I get the following error:

[image]

How can I change the com.organizationname part of the bundle identifier? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the App from the Simulator after changing the bundle identifier. Next time you build and run the App the connection to the Simulator should work fine.

If that does not help you can also reset the Simulator:

[image]

Comment: I initially did those things without any success. However, after an xcode restart, simulator restart, clean, clean build folder, it took the change.